# Insert dates starting from 00:00:00 and ending 23:59:59 in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a following code that groups `value` from `07:10:00` to `17:30:00`.

```py
import pandas as pd


dict = {"datetime" : ["2022-10-26 07:12:13", "2022-10-26 09:14:43", "2022-10-26 17:25:19"], "value" : [1, 3, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])

df = (
            df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq=f"5Min", key="time")])[
                "value"
            ]
            .sum()
            .reset_index(name="value")
        )

df = df.rename(columns={"time": "interval start"})
df.insert(
            1, "interval end", df["interval start"] + pd.Timedelta("5Min")
        )
```

But how can I prolong this group starting from `00:00:00` to `23:59:59` ?

Comment: What's the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple way to achieve:**

- First get the max, min times to find the actual start_time and end_time (you asked for day start time / end time)
- Create master dataframe with the required time limit and then merge with the actual dataframe.

**Including changes**

```
import pandas as pd


dict = {"datetime" : ["2022-10-26 07:12:13", "2022-10-26 09:14:43", "2022-10-26 17:25:19"], "value" : [1, 3, 5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])


m_df = pd.DataFrame(data={"time": [df["time"].min().replace(hour=0, minute=0,second=0), df["time"].max().replace(hour=23, minute=59,second=59)]})
m_df = m_df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq=f"5Min", key="time")).sum().reset_index()

df = (
            df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq=f"5Min", key="time")])[
                "value"
            ]
            .sum()
            .reset_index(name="value")
        )


df = m_df.merge(df, on='time', how='left').fillna(0)

df = df.rename(columns={"time": "interval start"})
df.insert(
            1, "interval end", df["interval start"] + pd.Timedelta("5Min")
        )

print(df.head())
```